# Stratification of minimal rational component and the dimension of the strata

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be Fano manifold of dimension $n$ over complex numbers. Further assume that $X$ has non-nef tangent bundles. Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a minimal rational component in $\text{Mor}(\mathbb{P}^1, X)$ with respect to $-K_X$. Then for each element $(f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to X) \in \mathcal{K}$, one has $f^*TX = \oplus_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a_i(f))$ with $a_1(f)\ge a_2(f) \ge...\ge a_n(f)$ and $a_1(f) \ge 2$. Let $V:= \{f \in \mathcal{K}:a_n(f) \le -1\}$. Then one can stratify $V$ as $V_{n-1} \subset V_{n-2} \subset ... \subset V_2 \subset V_1$, where $V_i:= \{ f \in \mathcal{K}: a_{n-i+1}(f) \le -1\}$. Assume $V$ is generically smooth and of co-dimension one in $\mathcal{K}$.

Question: (1) Is it true that $V_2 \ne V_1$ ?

(2) Can we say anything about the dimension of each starta ?

Comment: In the "generic" case, the subvariety $V$ of $\mathcal{K}$ has codimension equal to $1+\text{dim}(X)$, not equal to $1$. Then the image in $X$ has codimension $\geq 1$.  This is roughly the content of the theorem of Koll'ar-Miyaoka-Mori that every rational curve containing a "very general" point of $X$ is free.  The locus $V$, and indeed the loci $V_i$, can be defined as determinantal loci, but that is not so useful until you "compactify" $\mathcal{K}$ (and then extending the determinantal description is subtle).  Anyway, with your definition, the locus $V_1$ is automatically empty.

Comment: $V_1$ is precisely the rational curves which are not free. Thus if $V_1$ is empty, then every rational curve in $\mathcal{K}$ is free, which is not true in general when tangent bundle is not nef.

Comment: For example, in the case of intersection of two quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^5$ can be covered by lines, Then for  a general line the restriction of the tangent bundle has decomposition as $\mathcal{O}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O} \oplus  \mathcal{O}$ . On the other hand, on the special lines it has decomposition of the form $\mathcal{O}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)$ and these lines form a divisor.

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  Please read your post. I accept that you might have intended $V_1$ to mean something else, but with your current definitions and notations it equals the empty set.

Comment: According to my  definition in the post $V = V_1$. i.e., the set of rational curves  such that the number of negative degree direct summand in the decomposition of the tangent bundle restricted to the rational curve is at least $1$.  Whereas  $V_2$ is the is the set of rational curves  such that the number of negative degree direct summand in the decomposition of the tangent bundle restricted to the rational curve is at least $2$ etc. Please let me know if the definitions are  still unclear to you.

Comment: Read your definition of $V_i$ above.  Now consider what that definition gives when $i$ equals $1$.

Comment: I am sorry. $a_{i}$ should be replaced by $a_{n-i+1}$. I have corrected the error now.  Please let me know the if there is some easy answer to my question.

Comment: @JasonStarr In your first comment what do you mean by '' generic case'' and what is the proof for that statement ? at least a reference will be helpful.

Comment: I wrote something wrong.  The correct codimension in the generic case is 1 + the relative dimension of the evaluation morphism from $\text{Mor}(\mathbb{P}^1,X)$ to $X$, not 1 + the dimension of $X$.  I will try to find a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much.